# Let $p$ be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, find all roots of $x^{p-1}-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots

Let $p$ be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. Find all roots of $x^{p-1}-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

**Attempt at Solution**

I have to solve $x^{p-1}-1=0(\text{mod }p)$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$. This becomes $x^{p-1}=1(\text{mod }p)$.

$x^{p-1}=xx^p$ Let $b=\frac{x}{\sqrt[p]{x}}$. Then we have $b^p=1(\text{mod }p)$.

Then, by Fermat's Little Theorem, I know that $b=1(\text{mod }p)$, which is $b=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. So $\frac{x}{\sqrt[p]{x}}=1(\text{mod }p)=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

$\frac{x}{\sqrt[p]{x}}=x^{1-1/p}=1\Rightarrow x=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Is this at all right?

Comment: No. The implication $x^{1-1/p}=1~\Rightarrow~ x=1$ does not hold in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. Why would it? It's the same as $(-1)^2=1\Rightarrow -1=1$ in $\Bbb Q$. If you know Fermat's little theorem, try applying it to all nonzero elements of $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ (just see what Wikipedia says for example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ except $0$ is a root. By Fermat's little theorem $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ for any prime $p$ and $a$ not divisible by $p$.

If you don't like that answer then consider this. We know that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a field for prime $p$ so it's multiplicative group is a group of order $p-1$. So any element in the group when raised to the power $p-1$ must be $1$.